# setup mysql for wordpress manually

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I installed mysql and apache. Apache is serving wordpress correctly and I want to install wordpress via `install.php`. This fails at setup step 2 after inserting database name, user and password (error 500).

I suspect that I haven't correctly finished the mysql database setup.
So to check, I log in to mysql via `mysql -u root -p` and run `select database();` which returns null. So there is no database. Then when I call `create database wordpress` it says the db already exists. So what??

Just in case someone asks why not use xampp or wamp or the like: I want to set up everything by hand to learn the basics.

System setup: Windows 8.1 64 bit, mysql 5.7.21, apache 2.4, php 7.2.4 w/ thread safe

Comment: What is the output of show databases;

Comment: DATABASE() does not do what you think. -> [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_database)

Comment: Oh it shows some tables amongst which is wordpress. thanks for the hint. Any idea why the wordpress setup fails?

Comment: what do you get in the error logs? 500 error should be loged in the apache

Comment: It shows fatal error `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` and just before multiple warnings like `use of undefined constant DB_USER` / password / name / host. Which is strange because the wordpress form requests exactly those constants, doesn't it?

Comment: mysql_connect was removed from php7. http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php. idk. maybe something with your config. or an old wordpress version? (or you are missing some other database extension that wordpress requires like PDO or mysqli)

Comment: In my php.ini file, there is the line `extension=mysqli`. This was already set before I tested wordpress. Why does this not solve the mysql_connect problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini file you have to enable two settings:

- extension = mysqli
- extension_dir = "ext"

The root cause was that I had only activated the extension setting.
The website where I found this tip did not mention the requirement to also set the extension directory.

The final solution is from the [official guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) to install mysqli, which is very misleading in this regard:

For PHP > 5.3 it says

> On Windows, for PHP versions 5.3 and newer, the mysqli extension is
>   enabled and uses the MySQL Native Driver by default. This means you
>   don't need to worry about configuring access to libmysql.dll.

But this was not true for me. It did not work out of the box.
For older versions (e.g. ones which should not affect my version) it says

> As with enabling any PHP extension (such as php_mysqli.dll), the PHP
>   directive extension_dir should be set to the directory where the PHP
>   extensions are located. See also the Manual Windows Installation
>   Instructions. An example extension_dir value for PHP 5 is c:\php\ext.

This was the final hint that got it working.